# Posting image/video to Twitter

Tags: php, twitter, file-upload

When I trying to post an image or video using the Twitter API, I get the error message

> {"request":"/i/media/upload.json","error":"Segments do not add up
>   to provided total file size."}

Google doesn't have any information about this error. Twitter documentation is also no help.  What's wrong?

What I'm doing:

```
1. INIT uploading file

> $this->SetUrl('upload.twitter.com/i/media/upload.json?command=INIT&media_type=image%2Fpng&total_bytes='
> . $filesize)
>                 ->SendRequest('post');

2. APPEND chunks

> $reply = ['media' => $chunk];
> $this->SetQuery($reply);
> $this->SetUrl('upload.twitter.com/i/media/upload.json?command=APPEND&media_id='.$mediaId.'&segment_index='.$segment_id)->SendRequest('post');

3. When I FINALIZE, I get the error

> $this->SetUrl('upload.twitter.com/i/media/upload.json?command=FINALIZE&media_id='
> . $mediaId)->SendRequest('post');
```

Comment: Corrected grammar; improved formatting.  The actual problem presentation is good.

Comment: Have you resolved this yet? I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: Liza, my problem was that I was sent the wrong chunks. When sending a request to finalize, I generate an error that the amount of chunks is not equal to the total file size.

As soon as the computer will - will publish the code here

Answer (score 2):

```
// APPEND
    $ch = curl_init();
    $file = fopen($media, 'r');
    $chunk_id = 0;

    while (!feof($file)) {

        $append_headers = array();
        $chunk = fread($file, 1048576); // 1mb per chunk
        $boundary = $chunk_id.time();
        $params  = "--" . $boundary . "\r\n"
            . "Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n"
            . "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"blob\"\r\n"
            . "\r\n"
            . $chunk . "\r\n"
            . "--" . $boundary . "--";
        $append_headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params);
        $append_headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $boundary;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $append_headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->curl_config['useragent']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_dir . md5($this->UserName . $this->Password));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_dir . md5($this->UserName . $this->Password));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://upload.twitter.com/i/media/upload.json?command=APPEND&media_id=' . $init->media_id . '&segment_index=' . $chunk_id);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $chunk_id++;

    }
```

That's is my solution for posting chunks. Works great.